# How to implement retry logic with Task Parallel Library(TPL)

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retry a task multiple times based on user input in case of an exception in task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490307/retry-a-task-multiple-times-based-on-user-input-in-case-of-an-exception-in-task)

I'm looking for a way to implement retry logic in TPL.  I would like to have a generic function/class that will be able to return a Task which will execute a given action and in case of an exception will retry the task, up to the given retry count.  I tried playing with ContinueWith and have the callback create a new task in case of an exception, but it seems that it will only work for fixed amount of retries.   Any suggestions?

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        Task<int> taskWithRetry = CreateTaskWithRetry(DoSometing, 10);
        taskWithRetry.Start();
        // ...

    }

    private static int DoSometing()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static Task<T> CreateTaskWithRetry<T>(Func<T> action, int retryCount)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Any reason to do anything special to do with the TPL? Why not just make a wrapper for `Func<T>` itself?

```
public static Func<T> Retry(Func<T> original, int retryCount)
{
    return () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return original();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (retryCount == 0)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                // TODO: Logging
                retryCount--;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Note that you may want to add a `ShouldRetry(Exception)` method to allow certain exceptions (e.g. cancellation) abort without the retry.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have each action(after retry) run as a seperate task?

Comment: @Amos: Why? What would the advantage be?

Comment: This is similar to using ContinueWith to excecute task B after task A finishes instead of having a single task that excecutes A and then B.  This way other threads can get ahead after several retries, instead of after all the retries are done.

Comment: Could you please post an example of the usage of your Retry wrapper with an async method?

Comment: @SuperJMN: It isn't designed for async operations; I'd do that differently.

Comment: OK! then, please look into this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079087/observable-retry-doesnt-work-as-expected). Thanks in advance, Jon!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Task<T> CreateTaskWithRetry<T>(Func<T> action, int retryCount)
{
    Func<T> retryAction = () =>
    {
        int attemptNumber = 0;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                attemptNumber++;
                return action();
            }
            catch (Exception exception) // use your the exception that you need
            {
                // log error if needed
                if (attemptNumber == retryCount)
                    throw;
            }
        }
        while (attemptNumber < retryCount);

        return default(T);
    };

    return new Task<T>(retryAction);
}
```

Comment: I would like to have each retry attempt excecute on a seperate task.  This is similar to using ContinueWith to excecute task B after task A finishes instead of having a single task that excecutes A and then B. This way other threads can get ahead after several retries, instead of after all retries are done.