# convert starting dedicated threads to threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading

What would be the equivalent way, using ThreadPool, to achieve the code below:

Receiver is a class that I am instantiating

```
foreach (MobileAccounts MobileAccount in ReceiverAccounts)
{                        
    Receiver rec = new Receiver();
    ThreadStart starterParameters = delegate { rec.StartListener(MobileAccount); };
    Thread FeedbackThread = new Thread(starterParameters);
    FeedbackThread.Name = MobileAccount.FriendlyName;

    FeedbackThread.Start();                                                                                           
}
```

Comment: Which runtime version, can you use the Task Parallel Library?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 with 4.5 installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my original question:

```
foreach (MobileAccounts MobileAccount in ReceiverAccounts)
{
    Receiver rec = new Receiver();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { rec.StartListener(MobileAccount); }, null);                    


}
```

Comment: If the tasks you're launching are long-running, this runs the risk of locking up the thread pool.  Some of your tasks may not even run, if you have a large enough number of accounts.  The thread pool is designed for use with relatively short-lived tasks.

Comment: The number of threads will be a known constant in this case. 8 Threads at the most. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3):

Well you won't necessarily be able to name the threads if you switch to a ThreadPool, however you can just use the Task Parallel library to achieve your goals. [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

One way would be

```
foreach (MobileAccounts MobileAccount in ReceiverAccounts) {
  Receiver rec = new Receiver();
  Task.Run(() => rec.StartListener(MobileAccount));
}
```

Or even using Parallel.ForEach

```
Parallel.ForEach(ReceiverAccounts, 
                 MobileAccount => new Receiver().StartListener(MobileAccount));
```

Comment: Will any of these allow me to also dispose a specific thread?

Comment: @BossRoss what do you mean? should shouldn't kill or dispose threads in the ThreadPool, the thread would need to be reused.

Comment: @BossRoss are you talking about cleanup or remotely killing a listener?

Comment: The method being called will be a long running method. Should something go wrong inside a specific thread I need to terminate that specific thread and start it again.

Comment: A ThreadPool (and the TPL by extension) uses a pool of *common-use* threads to execute *workloads* (ie methods). If a *workload* fails, you submit it again. You don't have and shouldn't require any access to the actual thread. As for retrying with the TPL, check [this conversation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490307/retry-a-task-multiple-times-based-on-user-input-in-case-of-an-exception-in-task) for ways to do it with either Tasks or the `async\await` keywords

Comment: @BossRoss, when you say should something go wrong I need to terminate, how are you detecting something has gone wrong?

Comment: By a date time stamp in a database that I am checking from the main thread. If I see the date time is larger than two minutes I will need to "kill" that specific thread and start it again from scratch

Comment: @BossRoss, using the ThreadPool there is no safe way to do this, you cannot kill threads.  You would need to make your individual tasks more resilient and check themselves.  You could put code within the tasks code to poll and check a cancel variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();

  foreach (MobileAccounts MobileAccount in ReceiverAccounts)
  {
    var rec = new Receiver();
    var ct = tokenSource2.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.DoWorkEventArgs(rec, ct));
  }

 // Anywhere outside you can call tokenSource2.Cancel();


 private void DoWorkEventArgs(Receiver rec, CancellationToken ct)
 {
   // Were we already canceled?
   ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

   bool moreToDo = true;
   while (moreToDo)
   {
       // Poll on this property if you have to do 
       // other cleanup before throwing. 
       if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
         // Clean up here, then...
         ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       }
    }
 }
```