# Calling Asynchronous method after certain time has passed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, dispatcher

I have the following code in .Net C# that makes a call, and then evaluates the response. If the response is Pending, I want to wait 2 seconds, and make the call again.

I do not know how to do the "Wait 2 seconds" here, or how to use a timer that works with the synchronous method.

I am limited by the constraints of a PCL project.

```
private async Task<Response> ExecuteTask(Request request)
{
    var response = await GetResponse();

    switch(response.Status)
    {
        case ResponseStatus.Pending:
            //wait 2 seconds
            response = await ExecuteTask(request);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Would the following code be ok?

```
System.Threading.Timer timer;

private async Task<Response> ExecuteTask(Request request)
{
    var response = await GetResponse();

    switch(response.Status)
    {
        case ResponseStatus.Pending:
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async obj =>
        {
            response = await ExecuteTask(request);
        }, null, 1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to claim this is a very good idea, but you could await a Task.Delay? Its basically the same as Thread.Sleep for tasks (to my knowledge).

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to setup some kind of retry task.  Might want to see towards the bottom of this answer for an idea on how to implement it with async await.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10494424/1181408

Comment: I do not know how to do the timing. What do I use for the 2 seconds? A Timer?

Comment: Task.Delay is what you looking for.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET `Task.Delay` is *not* anything like `Sleep` other than the fact that something occurs after a certain amount of time.  i.e. `Task.Delay` does not put a thread into a wait state.  In fact it uses `System.Thread.Timer` under the covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In async you wait using `Task.Delay`

```
private async Task<Response> ExecuteTask(Request request)
{
    var response = await GetResponse();

    switch(response.Status)
    {
        case ResponseStatus.Pending:
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            response = await ExecuteTask(request);
            break;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Is Task.Delay not available for a PCL project? Seems not available in my project.

Comment: You can use the one in Microsoft.Bcl.Async with PCL instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx

Comment: @alitaleg Are you adding detail to your question to suggest you're limited to a PCL?

Comment: Any other possibilities without using MSFT.Bcl.Async?

Comment: @alitaleg: If you're writing a PCL (unless it's only for the newer platforms), you have to use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` just to get `async`/`await` working at all.

Comment: From what I can see, the project does not use Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Comment: Thanks! The TaskEx.Delay from the the Micorsoft.Bcl.Async library did the trick.