# How do I retry an antecedent async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, error-handling, continuations, retry-logic

I have a series of async calls to make with some dependent on other tasks completing before starting others. I would like to have retry logic for these calls due to them all being calls to external resources. Here is our prototype code without any exception handling or retry logic: (This does the job, but without any resiliency or error handling). After quite a bit of research, I need a bit of help putting this together in a resilient way.

```
Task uploadHdr = null;
Task uploadElig = null;
Task ImportHdrCPA = null;
Task ImportHdrCCRS = null;
Task ImportEligCPA = null;
Task ImportEligCCRS = null;
Task ProcessCPA = null;
Task ProcessCCRS = null;

//Connect to blob storage
CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string to blob storage");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ourcontainer");           

//Import Header to Choice PA
using (SqlConnection conCPA = new SqlConnection("connection string for CPA"))
using (SqlConnection conCCRS = new SqlConnection("connection string for CCRS"))
{
    conCPA.Open();
    conCCRS.Open();

    //Upload HDR file
    CloudBlockBlob hdrBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Header.txt");
    FileStream fsHdr = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Development\Header.txt");
    uploadHdr = hdrBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fsHdr);
    allTasks.Add(uploadHdr);
    Console.WriteLine("Started Header Upload " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());

    //Upload eligibility segment file
    CloudBlockBlob elgBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Detail.txt");
    FileStream fsElig = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Development\Detail.txt");
    uploadElig = elgBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fsElig);
    allTasks.Add(uploadElig);
    Console.WriteLine("Started Detail Upload " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());

    while (allTasks.Any())
    {
        Task.WhenAny(allTasks.ToArray());

        if (uploadHdr.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ImportHdrCPA == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmdHdrCPA = new SqlCommand("dbo.spImportHeader", conCPA) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            cmdHdrCPA.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmdHdrCPA.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = "Header.txt";
            ImportHdrCPA = cmdHdrCPA.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            allTasks.Add(ImportHdrCPA);
            Console.WriteLine("Started Header Import 1 " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        if (ImportHdrCPA.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ImportHdrCCRS == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spNCEligibilityImportHeader", conCCRS) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = "CSC_NCEligibility_Hdr_i_20191105.txt";
            ImportHdrCCRS = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            allTasks.Add(ImportHdrCCRS);
            Console.WriteLine("Started Header Import 2 " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        if(uploadElig.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ImportEligCPA == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spImportDetail", conCPA) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = "Detail.txt";
            ImportEligCPA = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            allTasks.Add(ImportEligCPA);
            Console.WriteLine("Started Detail Import 1 " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        if(ImportEligCPA != null && ImportEligCPA.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ImportEligCCRS == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spImportDetail", conCCRS) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = "Detail.txt";
            ImportEligCCRS = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            allTasks.Add(ImportEligCCRS);
            Console.WriteLine("Started Detail Import 2 " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        if (ImportHdrCPA.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ImportEligCPA != null && ImportEligCPA.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ProcessCPA == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spProcess", conCPA) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            ProcessCPA = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            allTasks.Add(ProcessCPA);
            Console.WriteLine("Started Processing 1 " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        }

        if (ImportHdrCCRS != null && ImportHdrCCRS.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ImportEligCCRS != null && ImportEligCCRS.IsCompletedSuccessfully && ProcessCCRS == null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spProcess", conCCRS) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 0 };
            ProcessCCRS = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            allTasks.Add(ProcessCCRS);
            Console.WriteLine("Started Processing 2 " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        }                  

        if (ProcessCCRS != null && ProcessCPA != null)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());
            allTasks.Clear();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are the errors that you are seeing? This seems like an opinion-based question at the moment - which you should steer clear from

Comment: Have you looked at [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)?

Comment: I have looked at Polly, but was having trouble getting it to work properly. Polly will handle the retry portion fine, but does not seem to allow me to use ContinueWith to handle the antecedents. I know there has to be a better approach than the loop and check method I am using. Mark Davies: I tried several things from the following article, but kept running into an object ref not set error I could not resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490307/retry-a-task-multiple-times-based-on-user-input-in-case-of-an-exception-in-task

Comment: UPDATE: I added the following line: var retryPolicy = Policy
                .Handle<Exception>()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); at the top of the code, then changed the line starting with uploadHdr = to uploadHdr = retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => { await hdrBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fsHdr); }); This ends in an object ref not set error on the last line of the code in the void Main(string[] args) with no indication of what actually failed.

Comment: The error is thrown when it hits the Task.WhenAny line specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that I have used in a WinForms application for giving the option to the user to either retry or cancel an I/O request. If an exception is thrown in whatever code you give it, then it will pop up a dialog with the exception message and ask the user if they'd like to retry or cancel. If they choose to retry, it'll retry. If they choose to cancel, it'll rethrow the exception.

If you're not using WinForms, you can modify how the request to the user is made - or just retry a specific number of times without user intervention.

Even if you are using WinForms, you may need to make some modifications to the code. I put this in the code for a form, hence the call to `Invoke`.

This has two versions: one for synchronous and one for asynchronous.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gives the option to retry if the provided action throws an exception
/// </summary>
/// <param name="action">The action to perform</param>
public void RetryableAction(Action action) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            action();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            var dr = DialogResult.Retry;
            Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => dr = MessageBox.Show(this,
                $"There was an error:\r\n{e.Message}\r\n\r\nDo you want to retry?", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)));

            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel) {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

public async Task RetryableAction(Func<Task> action) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            await action();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            var dr = DialogResult.Retry;
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => dr = MessageBox.Show(this,
                $"There was an error:\r\n{e.Message}\r\n\r\nDo you want to retry?", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)));

            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel) {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how you would use it (in the case of the asynchronous version):

```
await RetryableAction(async () => {
    uploadHdr = await hdrBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fsHdr);
});
```

Comment: I attempted this with slight modification (I don't want to await the calls so other tasks can be started), and ended at an object ref not set error.  uploadHdr = RetryableAction(async () =>
                {
                    await hdrBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fsHdr);
                }, retryCounter);

Comment: You will have to debug and see what's null that you didn't expect to be. Maybe `hdrBlob`?

Comment: Gabriel - It shows the error as occurring on the last line (the actual closing brace) of the void Main, and gives no other indication of what failed. A breakpoint on the line inside the RetryAbleAction call shows hdrBlob as being set and valid.

Comment: If this is a console app, change your `Main` method declaration to `public static async Task Main(string[] args)` and use `await` in front of `RetryableAction`. Otherwise, your application won't actually be waiting for it to finish.

Comment: The error is thrown when it hits the Task.WhenAny line specifically.

Comment: [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) returns a `Task<Task>`. You need to use the return value for it to be of any use to you. For example: `var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(allTasks)`. Then `finishedTask` will be the `Task` that finished.

Comment: Gabriel - I don;t want the app to wait on the first call. I want it to continue processing some of the other calls until it reaches one that is dependent on the first task completing. We are uploading 2 files to 2 different DBs, then running a proc in each DB to process the data. I added the var finishedTask = to the line for Task.WehnAny() and it still throws the same  object ref error at the same location with no additional details.

Comment: Using `Task.WhenAny` is useless unless you await it. If you don't await it, your code will immediately move on to the next line even if no `Task` has finished.

Comment: Gabriel - The error was difficult to resolve because I was running in Release like an idiot. The error was occurring on one of the if statements and had nothing to do with your code or Polly. Your solution and Polly both work for the retry logic, and both work well. Thank you for the help!!!