# How to re-enqueue a failed background async task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

Good day, I'm trying to create a general purpose task queue service that executes in the background using `BackgroundService`. I avoided using a `Delegate` function `Func<T1,T2, OuT>` as input to `EnqueueTask(Task<ResponseHelper> newTask)` method because I wanted a generic solution, so I opted to pass a `Task<ResponseHelper>` instead. But this solution does not allow me to re-enqueue a failed task inside `ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)` because the task returns an instance of `ResponseHelper` which is not a copy of the failed task. Kindly help me correct the code I have to return a dequeued task from `DequeueTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` function instead of an instance of `ResponseHelper`.

```
public interface ITaskQueueHelper
{
    void EnqueueTask(Task<ResponseHelper> newTask);

    Task<ResponseHelper> DequeueTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class TaskQueueHelper : ITaskQueueHelper
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim signal;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Task<ResponseHelper>> taskQueue;

    public TaskQueueHelper()
    {
        signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

        taskQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Task<ResponseHelper>>();
    }

    public void EnqueueTask(Task<ResponseHelper> newTask)
    {
        if (newTask == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newTask));
        }

        taskQueue.Enqueue(newTask);

        signal.Release();
    }

    public async Task<ResponseHelper> DequeueTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

        taskQueue.TryDequeue(out var currentTask);

        /*I need to return currentTask here, instead of an instance of ResponseHelper*/

        return await currentTask;
    }
}

public class TaskQueueService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ITaskQueueHelper taskQueue;

    private readonly ILogger<TaskQueueService> logger;

    public TaskQueueService(
        ITaskQueueHelper _taskQueue,
        ILogger<TaskQueueService> _logger)
    {
        logger = _logger;

        taskQueue = _taskQueue;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ResponseHelper response = await taskQueue.DequeueTaskAsync(stoppingToken);

            try
            {
                if (!response.Status.Equals(ResultCode.Success))
                {
                    /*I need to re-enqueue a failed task here*/

                    //taskQueue.EnqueueTask(currentTask);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, $"Error occurred executing {nameof(TaskQueueService)}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just a heads up, if you needs jobs and such i've had some succes with using hangfire instead.

Comment: @sommmen Thank you for the heads up, I will take this under consideration if I fail to get a work around from other soft-engineers.

Comment: wel its hard to grasp what you're doing here. i mean if you want to requeue the task you need to keep a reference to it, so it would either need to be added to your response or your scheduling service should keep a reference to it. there's no other way

Comment: @sommmen I'm trying to add tasks to the queue using `EnqueueTask(Task<ResponseHelper> newTask)`, as opposed to adding them via `Delegate`, the task returns an instance of type `ResponseHelper` but when `DequeueTaskAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` function runs `return await currentTask;`  it returns an instance of ResponseHelper not the current dequeued task. I want this function to return the currentTask. That is the problem I need a solution to.

Comment: `Because integerTask is a Task<TResult>, it contains a Result property of type TResult. In this case, TResult represents an integer type. When await is applied to integerTask, the await expression evaluates to the contents of the Result property of integerTask. The value is assigned to the ret variable.` from msdn. you see that is not how this works..

Comment: retrying happens something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490307/retry-a-task-multiple-times-based-on-user-input-in-case-of-an-exception-in-task

Comment: If you need something a little richer than `BackgroundService`, you can checkout [Runly](https://www.runly.io). Sorry for the plug but I think it could help in situations like this where retrying and fault tolerance for background tasks are important.

Answer (score 0):

for retrying you could do:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ResponseHelper response = await taskQueue.DequeueTaskAsync(stoppingToken);

            try
            {
                if (!response.Status.Equals(ResultCode.Success))
                {
                    // Retry the task.
                    response = await taskQueue.DequeueTaskAsync(stoppingToken);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, $"Error occurred executing {nameof(TaskQueueService)}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would retry the task once, and you can do a while loop to do it several times

Comment: also take a look at polly https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly for retrying. Its a popular library and part of the .net foundation.

Comment: how does the idea of adding a Property in `ITaskQueueHelper interface` sound? `public Task<ResponseHelper> ExecutingTask { set; get; }` and assign a copy of the dequeued task. I can then do something like this `taskQueue.EnqueueTask(taskQueue.ExecutingTask);`. May have your thoughts on this?

Comment: @yaddly i gues that would work aswell, however perhaps it would be better to protect it more, and opt for placing it into the derived class instead, so only your backgroundservice can fiddle with it. You don't want any other implementers fiddle around with the task i gues. You can then extend the dervied/interface classes with some functions you might needs like IsActiveTaskRunning or so.

Comment: this would adhere to the open for extension closed for modification principle.

Comment: thank you for your kind help and guidance in resolving this enigma