# How to retry a task in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, concurrency, task-parallel-library

The [accepted answer to earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494424/200449) question "Retry a task multiple times based on user input in case of an exception in task" provides a code in C# 5.0

I am not familiar with .NET async, await constructs using .NET 4.0 having difficulties to put together the code in C# 4.0. The other answers also contain puzzles

Could you provide me with a complete C# 4.0 source code, i.e. sample,  how to retry a task in C# including the handling of exception and allowing cancellation without retry?

Comment: -1 The combination of your attitude in followups **while not improving your question in response to clear weaknesses in it** plus the fact that reading this valueless question and answer wasted minutes of my time set makes me want this question gone. Can you followup with what you've got so far and/or what the missing bits are or delete the question please. Or accept an answer

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you're asking for a solution similar to the one suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090026/how-to-implement-retry-logic-with-task-parallel-librarytpl). Here, Jon Skeet gives an implementation of a Retry method for general actions. Additionally, you are asking the inclusion of execption handling the possibility to cancel the operation without retry. In that context, Jon also mentions the possibility to incorporate a ShouldRetry(Exception) method that you can use to determine whether is sensible to retry. Thus, I've incorporated some sample code into the original code by Jon:

```
public static Func<T> Retry(Func<T> original, int retryCount)
{
    return () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return original();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (retryCount == 0 || !ShouldRetry(e))
                {
                    throw;
                }

                // TODO: Logging
                retryCount--;
            }
        }
   };
}

public static bool ShouldRetry(Exception e) {
    return (e is MySpecialExceptionThatAllowsForARetry)
}
```

Does that clarify the answers to the other question?

Edit: Other have correctly pointed out that my code could be simplified/specialized in the considered case. The above code wraps a `Func` into a *retriable* (or rather *retrying*) `Func`. A simpler form that fits the questions would be

```
public static T Retry(Task<T> original, int retryCount)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            return original();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (retryCount == 0 || !ShouldRetry(e))
            {
                throw;
            }

            // TODO: Logging
            retryCount--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just copy-pasted the code of [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090049/200449). I saw it and I have difficulties to put together the complete sample code.

Comment: @fulproof -  Maybe it would be helpful if you asked specific questions about the difficulties you are having with this sample.  It seems reasonably clear to me.

Comment: @fulproof: Yes, i **mostly** copy and pasted the answer to another question (that is, to a question you did not mention in your question), but please also consider the slight changes I've made. Additionally, I've tried to find an answer that makes use of plain .NET 4.0 code (which it, afaik, does), but it seems that the problem of understanding seems to lie elsewhere. So, it would be helpful if you could follow Andrew's advice in order to identify these problems?

Comment: @bigge, I'd appreciate a sample, i.e. complete code that I can compile and run

Comment: Returning Func<T> looks not necessary here. You can just run the loop inside.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper, in order to specify good question it is necessary to know answer beforehand. Hope the question and the answer are more clear in context of [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472537/2031316) It was not clear where (or how) to use provided in answers `Retry()` method (or how the code snippets relate to each other and/or original question)

Comment: My question was not on how to modify existing in answers code but how to put them together. In that particular case I was asking how to use (call) that method `Retry()` but not how to modify (complicate or simplify) or explain it. I am not even getting what was the problem to post the complete code of console app I've been asking about from the start

Answer (score -5):

Well, if to reference the [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090049/2031316) in conjunction with [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090026/how-to-implement-retry-logic-with-task-parallel-librarytpl) then it should have specified:

```
private static Task<T> CreateTaskWithRetry<T>(Func<T> action, int retryCount)
```

in place of:

```
public static Func<T> Retry(Func<T> original, int retryCount)
```

Comment: The idea is that you would simply provide the method in that answer to `Task.Run`, rather than providing some other function and trying to retry the task.  The method itself has no need to move itself to a thread pool thread.

Comment: No thanks.  You seem to be a rather unreasonable and demanding person unwiling to accept anything but someone doing the entirety of your work for you.  When someone took time to help you by providing the majority of the solution to your problem although generalized you were not receptive at all.

Comment: @Servy, could you please put your comment as answer here or there? I'm not getting it! Do you refer to .NET 4.5's `Task.Run()` absent in .NET 4.0 when I specifically asked to migrate answers and code there to .NET 4.0?

Comment: If you need a 4.0 solution you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, as that's all that `Run` does anyway.  I would think that you'd be capable of deducing that on your own.

Comment: I had difficulties to (quickly) understand and put together existing answers so I asked. Instead, I got a dupe of existing answer with the same inconsistency hindering its comprehension. Everybody is capable of deducing answers on his your own, it is just the matter of time and experience. From this pov, no questions can have the right of existence

Comment: "I would think that you'd be capable of deducing that on your own" - if you know the basic concepts of studying that you would know that "on your own" is less efficient than interactively and associatively

Comment: I disagree.  It would have taken you far less time and effort to spend a few seconds doing some trivial research into the problem and come to the solution on your own than to spend the time asking others to do your work for you when you have put no time or effort into it yourself.  That ends up consuming more of even your own time, and when you add in the time of others the efficiency is clearly worse.  Now for a more complex question that you couldn't answer in literally 20 seconds of Google searching, it's very possible that asking would be more efficient.

Comment: @ Servy, I did not ask to spend others their time , it is completely voluntarily to read or answer questions here. I am using SO as a notepad for my learning exercises progress. I would have agreed with your arguments if you did not spend on off-topic non-questioning and non-answering arguments here more time than I did on in-topic question. Please use your searching capabilities for participating in correct and wise questions suited for you! Or open the topic  in meta.SP if you cannot live without such discussions! Thanks

Comment: -1 this is not an  answer